# What happens if you chained delegatecalls?

Tags: solidity, contract-design, contract-invocation, delegatecall

Solidity docs say "only the code of the given address is used, all other aspects (storage, balance, ...) are taken from the current contract." This is useful when creating a library.

But what happens if you chain delegatecall( )?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chains of `delegatecall(..)` will still retain the original `msg.sender`, storage, balance, etc values from the calling contract.

```
contract A {
    function indirect() {
        B.doit();
    }
    function direct() {
        C.doit();
    }
}

library B {
    function doit() {
        C.doit();
    }
}

library C {
    function doit() {
        msg.sender.send(this.balance);
    }
}
```

In the above set of contracts, `A.direct()` and `A.indirect()` will behave the same.  The only difference is that `A.indirect()` will involve an additional stack depth increase since it chains `A > B > C` rather than directly from `A > C`.