# What's the value of `this` inside a library function when called via a delegatecall?

Tags: solidity, evm, library, delegatecall

Imagine a contract **C** that makes a delegatecall to a library **L**.

**C** -> **L**

What's the value of `this` inside **L**:  address(**C**) or address(**L**) ?

---

If now that **L** makes a normal call to another contract **D**.

**C** -> **L** -> **D**

What's the value of`msg.sender` inside **D**: address(**C**) or address(**L**) ?

Comment: I tried in the past and recall it's C in both cases, but I will have to test again.  This is also related: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2259/what-happens-if-you-chained-delegatecalls